# Element in centered between two points with offset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following structure:

```
 export interface Position {
     x: number
      y: number
}
        
        const [startPos, setStartPos] = useState({x: 0, y: 0})
        const [endPos, setEndPos] = useState({x: 0, y: 0})
        // which are modified in the place in the application
    
     const centerX = startPos.x + (endPos.x - startPos.x) / 2
     const centerY = startPos.y + (endPos.y - startPos.y) / 2
```

I have the following element

```
<Button style={{
                 left: centerX,
                 top: centerY,
                 position: "absolute",
               }}/>
```

This way everything is perfect and fine
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWxnV.png)

however when I try to offset the top by 50:

```
<Button style={{
                     left: centerX,
                     top: centerY + 50,
                     position: "absolute",
                   }}/>
```

When its vertical is fine however when it becomes horizontal its start to looks really bad

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7LeF.png)
[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bNeu.png)

Comment: The button looks to be identical in good and bad cases.

Comment: In the bad cases the button is not "attached" to the line

Comment: Ah you haven't mentioned a line, I assumed that was some background image.

Comment: Yeah, adding 50 to the top will move the whole thing "down" by 50, so it won't line up in some cases.  What output are you hoping for?  Why are you adding 50 at all?

Comment: @James I want to have multiple elements on the "line" (and the line is not static and the user can move it), ex: (- represents 10)
-------- Button ----- Textfield ----- Button

Comment: Do you wish to align the btn to the line as centered? Set the origin to center, it will use upper left by default, if im reading your question correctly that is..  or transform 50% negatively.

Comment: @Rmaxx I am okay with it being upper left as long as I can offset it